# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvtkCommon

Tags: linux, static-libraries, vtk

I try to learn how to use realityGrid so I use cmake to build some samples. After finishing use ccmake command, I tried to use make command. But I'm keeping to get the errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvtkCommon
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvtkFiltering
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvtkGraphics
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvtkImaging
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvtkIO
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvtkRendering
```

I found the libvtkCommon.a in /usr/lib/vtk-5.10. What should I do? Thanks ahead.

Comment: I tried to move all the missing lib files to /usr/lib, then it found the libraries but all the methods seem to be undifined like:undefined reference to `vtkPlane::New()'.

Comment: You really shouldn't move libraries around like that.  That has the potential to break other applications.  The issue is getting your library path setup correctly.

Answer (score 0):

you should install the package containing the "vtk" libraries so ld can find them.

if you installed them manually you need to add the path at which those files are located to the library path configuration.

http://blog.andrewbeacock.com/2007/10/how-to-add-shared-libraries-to-linuxs.html

Comment: I've tried the method you gave me, but it didn't work... Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell CMake that you require the VTK module.  I haven't used CMake much, but I believe the line you need is something like:

```
find_package(VTK REQUIRED NO_MODULE)
include(${VTK_USE_FILE})
```

If that doesn't work, you could probably fall back to something like this:

```
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH ${CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH} /usr/lib/vtk-5.10)
```

The bad part about the last line is that it won't port well to other environments where the version is slightly different.

Comment: The cmake part is finished by someone esle. There is a variable called  VTK_DIR after I run cmake command and it has been set to be /usr/lib/vtk-5.10.

Comment: Are you building for the right version of VTK?  In other words, are the headers for one version and are you trying to link to a different version?  Maybe 6.x versus 5.x?